# When enabling the OrbitCam script it's changing the camera view and position how can I enable the it but keep the camera view and position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game start when the camera is at this position :

[image: Camera start position]

Then the camera move smooth slowly to this position :
Using this script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayingInGameScenesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject camera;
    public LockController lockController;
    public GameObject uiTextsImage;
    public float transitionSpeed = 5f;
    public Transform currentView;

    // The initial offset from the target.
    private Vector3 offset;
    private bool newGame = true;
    private bool playingScene = true;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        currentView.position = new Vector3(43.4f, 1f,-6f);
        offset = camera.transform.position - currentView.position;
    }

    public void PlayingSceneInGame()
    {
        PlayingSceneStatesControls(true);
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayingTime());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && newGame == true)
        {
            PlayingSceneInGame();
            newGame = false;
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (playingScene == false)
        {
            //Lerp position
            camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(camera.transform.position, currentView.position, Time.deltaTime * transitionSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void PlayingSceneStatesControls(bool LockState)
    {
        lockController.LockControl(LockState);

        if (LockState == true)
        {
            uiTextsImage.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            uiTextsImage.SetActive(false);
            playingScene = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayingTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        PlayingSceneStatesControls(false);
    }
}
```

[image: New camera position]

Now at this point I want to check and know when the camera is not moving anymore in the LateUpdate and then when the camera stopped moving to enable true the OrbitCam script :

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class OrbitCam : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //All the variables used in this class(Look below to see what they do. :D   )
        private const float Y_ANGLE_MIN = 0.0f;
        private const float Y_ANGLE_MAX = 50.0f;
        private const float DISTANCE_MAX = 10.0f;
        private const float DISTANCE_MIN = 0.1f;
        private const float TRANS_MIN = 1.0f;
        private const float TRANS_MAX = 2.0f;
    
        public Transform lookAt;
        public Transform camTransform;
        public GameObject player;
    
        private Camera cam;
    
        public float distance = 5.0f;
        private float currentX = 0.0f;
        private float currentY = 0.0f;
        private float sensitivityX = 4.0f;
        private float sensitivityY = 1.0f;
        private float trandis;
    
        public Vector3 height = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    
        private bool below = false;
        private List<Renderer> playerRenderers = new List<Renderer>();
    
        private void Start()
        {
            //Makes camTransform a transform. :)
            camTransform = transform;
            //Sets variable cam value to the main camera
            cam = Camera.main;
    
            foreach (Transform child in player.transform)
            {
                if (child.GetComponent<Renderer>() != null)
                {
                    playerRenderers.Add(child.GetComponent<Renderer>());
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void Update()
        {
            //Makes the camera move by looking at the axis of the mouse(Also multiplied by the seisitivity.)
            currentX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
            currentY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
    
            //Limits the Y variable
            currentY = Mathf.Clamp(currentY, Y_ANGLE_MIN, Y_ANGLE_MAX);
    
            //Thiago Laranja's scrollwheel implemetation.
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) { distance += 0.2f; }
            if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0) { distance -= 0.2f; }
    
            //Makes sure that these variables never go over the max and be les than the min. :) 
            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance, DISTANCE_MIN, DISTANCE_MAX);
            trandis = Mathf.Clamp(distance, TRANS_MIN, TRANS_MAX) - 1;
    
            for (int i = 0; i < playerRenderers.Count; i++)
            {
                //Sets players transparency(Make sure that player materials rendering mode has set to transparent or other mode that supports transparency).
                playerRenderers[i].material.color = new Color(playerRenderers[i].material.color.r, playerRenderers[i].material.color.g, playerRenderers[i].material.color.b, trandis);
    
                //Disables the object from rendering if your're at distance 0.8.
                if (distance <= 0.8f) { playerRenderers[i].enabled = false; }
                if (distance > 0.8f) { playerRenderers[i].enabled = true; }
            }
            //If close enough to the character sinp into distance of 0.1(If distance is 0 the camera cant be rotated.)
            if (distance <= 0.8f && below == false) { distance = 0.1f; below = true; }
            if (distance >= 0.8f && below == true) { below = false; }
        }
        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            //Subtracts hte distance from Z coordinate
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
    
            //Creates an quaternion for rotation(too bad that we cannot use Vector3. :D   )
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentY, currentX, 0);
    
            //Sets the cameras position and makes it look at player.
            camTransform.position = lookAt.position + height + rotation * dir;
            camTransform.LookAt(lookAt.position + height);
        }
    }
```

- I don'y know how to check when the camera finished/stopped moving to the target position ?
- When I'm enabling the OrbitCam for now I'm doing it manual checking the enable box in the editor the OrbitCam change the camera view and position and I want that when I'm enabling the OrbitCam script that it will keep the view and position of the camera in the second screenshot.  Not to keep that view and position all the time only for starting the gameplay part.  but what I'm getting when enabling the OrbitCam script is :

[image: camera view and position after enabling the OrbitCam script and I want when enabling the script first time that the view and position to be kept as in the second screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend to use a animation on the camera. This has the big advantage that you can change the camera position like you do in the script and you have the option to set animation events. So you can call a function at the end of the animation. So if the camera animation is over, the camera is now in the correct position, you can enable the orbit cam. It is also very simple to set up! Hope that helps you!

Comment: Or using Vector3 distance with threshold is working fine too. My main problem is why when enable the orbitcam script it's changing the camera view and position and not continue from it's current camera position and view.

Comment: I really think you don't apply your previous transform to the camera. I know, that you set the cam object to the main camera but down below near the end you set the position without keeping the previous position. So maybe you need something like an offset to store the information about the previous camera position.